# CSS properties out of whack when adding button

Tags: html, css, button, styles, alignment

I have my page set up the way I want but when I try to add a button beneath the image on the left side of the page everything go a little crazy. I've been struggling with this for a little while not sure what to try next

Here's a visual:

http://jsfiddle.net/xFD8q/10/

Thanks

Comment: Well, for one thing, your HTML is invalid. If you're going to use a table for layout (a seriously bad idea) you need to have your content in `<td>` elements.

Comment: not sure what you mean. should i change my divs to columns <td>'s ?

Comment: You might find [this](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/table) to be a helpful staring point. It looks like you've gotten off on the wrong foot HTML wise.

Comment: like this one..[http://jsfiddle.net/qgRqt/](http://jsfiddle.net/qgRqt/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Revise your HTML, mixing DIVS with Tables isn't usually the best idea.
If you're unsure that your HTML is valid you can validate it via W3C Markup Validation found [here](http://validator.w3.org/)

I made a fiddle with a revised markup but left the refactoring of the CSS to you.
The fiddle has inline CSS which is *not* recommended but it was the fastest way to do it! :)

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FAusA/)

Good luck! :D